# Component re initializing when navigating within the page with different states

Tags: angular

I have requirment to navigate within the page with different states .But when state is changed component is re initializing and losing previously values.How to prevent component re initializing. I am using stateservice.transitionto for navigation within the page.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you provide more information along with some snippets of your code that demonstrate your issue. Or a stackblitz.com link example? I do something similar, reading new state from the url. But there is not enough info here to know if my techniques are applicable to your scenario. Thanks!

Comment: And I just looked it up ... stateservice.transitionto is from the AngularJS UI router. Is this an Angular question (v2+) or AngularJS question (v1.x)?